# Problema con SearchView de Android

Tags: android, searchview

Todo lo que escribo en el buscador se repite en un texto con fondo negro y no me gusta nada no quiero que aparezca y no encuentro el modo. Adjunto foto. Uso java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, puedes revisar si alguno de las funciones de accesibilidad de android están activados.

Comment: Hola, nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask] que te brinda información de como realizar preguntas en el sitio, estas sean bien recibidas y además obtengas la ayuda requerida, te sugerimos modificar el formato de tu pregunta agrega lo que investigaste o trataste, saludos.